# TRS-80 POKE Cursor Table Smiley?

Tags: cursors, z80

I'm trying to remember the POKE command to change the cursor on a TRS-80 Computer to a smiley face.

POKE 16419,x will change the cursor.

I cannot find a list of "x's"!

I know that 255 gives a rocketship.
Somewhere between 249-250 are gender symbols, etc.
Is there a table somewhere with all these symbols? I have googled and googled and due to the onset of SMILEY emoji, I think the answer to this is obfuscated...

Here is a nice place to try these, by the way: 
http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~pphillip/trs80.html

Thanks,
Rose

Comment: Ira Goldklang has written back to me with code to display chars, except it doesn't work on the emulator I'm using; it will print up to a certain number and then some of the chars don't seem to print. 
FOR X=32 TO 255:PRINT X;CHR$(X);" ";:NEXT X

Comment: Here is an answer for anyone who is looking for the answer here: printing the characters directly to the video memory will work: 
FOR X=0 TO 255 : POKE 15360+X, X : NEXT X

Answer (score 2):

FOR X=0 TO 255 : POKE 15360+X, X : NEXT X
will print the characters to the video memory. The smiley is 196. Thanks to Adam V.L. for the help!
[Here is a screenshot of the character set and the smiley cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF7YJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

[This site has a list of characters for the TRS-80](http://www.48k.ca/fonts.html) and its equivalent in UNICODE.

The smiley is the decimal 196 (UNICODE codepoint is U+263a):

```
196 ☺   &#x263a;    ☺
```